# NodeJs Gulp - confirm before starting task

Tags: node.js, gulp, prompt, confirm

I have a very heavy gulp task that I want to ask the user if he really wants to start the task.

I already saw the [gulp-confirm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-confirm)  and [gulp-prompt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-prompt) but it's not helping me:
I don't want to pipe the 'confirm' I just don't want to start the heavy task before user confirmation.

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
gulp.task('confirm', [], function ()
  {
            //Ask the confirm question here and cancel all task if the user abort
            prompt.confirm({
                message: 'This task will create a new tag version\n. Are you sure you want to continue?',
                default: true
            });
  });

    gulp.task('Build Release QA', ['confirm'], function ()//use this task to make release to QA
    {
        //very heavy task, don't start it if user abort it from 'confirm' task

    });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no need for a Gulp plugin, actually the package those two wrap around -- `inquirer` -- does anything you need:

```
var inquirer = require('inquirer');

gulp.task('default', function(done) {
    inquirer.prompt([{
        type: 'confirm',
        message: 'Do you really want to start?',
        default: true,
        name: 'start'
    }], function(answers) {
        if(answers.start) {
            gulp.start('your-gulp-task');
        }
        done();
    });
});
```

It's important you pass the `done` callback and call it once you are in the callback function of `inquirer`, so your task doesn't end prematurely.

That's one of the better things in Gulp: You might not need those plugins ;-)

Comment: I'd add, to prevent 'your-gulp-task' from being run directly, you can set a nonce and pass it to the gulp task. Otherwise, devs can call 'gulp your-gulp-task' and bypass all this confirmation business

Comment: can you explain a little more why the 'done' callback is important? thnx

Comment: This code will not work with the current version of the inquirer module.  `inquirer.prompt()` returns a promise so you have to use `inquirer.prompt(questions).then(function(answers) { // your code })` instead of the comma construct.